# How to use Erlang4Android and SL4A

Tags: android, scripting, erlang, sl4a

I'm trying to use Erang on my Android device. I have already installed Erlang4android app with also SL4A and I'm able to open an Erlang shell.
Well, now I want to run an Erlang node with specific name, cookie and so on but I didn't found an example about how to make a script for SL4A to do this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.
Mat

Comment: Cookie and node name are set as arguments to the `erl` executable used to start Erlang, see: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html No need for any scripts. Simply start with `erl -sname myname -setcookie mycookie`.

Comment: Yes, it's true in a "normal environment" but in Android OS I think that is a little bit different.

Comment: How do you start Erlang on Adroid? If it's started from an App icon or something then it maybe just a matter of setting proper arguments in the shortcut. Also, don't forget that many of those values you can set programmatically once the Erlang shell is started, e.g. this is how I set the node name (`net_kernel:start/1`) and cookie (`erlang:set_cookie/2`) on an already running node: https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/src/bld_lib.erl#L365

Comment: I installed the Erlang4android package that provide the Erlang 17 build with all the modules. Then I installed SL4A app that it has a list of "interpreters" (I haven't yet understood what it means), I select Erlang and I can see a shell Erlang ready to use. This node hasn't the property that I have configured in the Erlang4android app (sname, cookie ....).